# Magento 1.9.01 (patched) Trouble with onepage checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento1.9.0.1

Am having trouble with the onepage checkout on an installation of **Magento 1.9.0.1**.  Where the response of  `/checkout/onepage/saveBilling` is blank.  Form details are being passed through but the script effectively bombs out at a key point.

In

> OnepageController.php

```
$result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
```

just ends here.  I have added a lot of Mage::log()  into the Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php   saveBilling  function  and it seemingly gets all the way to the

```
return array(); 

  public function saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId)
  {
   ...
  Mage::log("this logs ok and data seems to be set prior",null,"mymag.log");
  return array();    // this seems to cause the process to stop
  Mage::log("Should have already returned an array() and not get here - this does not log",null."mymag.log");
  }
```

However  back in the Onepagecontroller.php

a   Mage::log() after the function call does not run

```
Mage::log("about to call saveBilling - this log works",null,"mymag.log");
$result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
Mage::log("this does not log...WHY!?!",null,"mymag.log");
```

Have spent ages trying to get this to work....help please

Comment: seemingly I need to add my bounty to an answer although no actual answer hit the nail on the head.  Still wondering what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that a server php module was not installed on the live server.  The module was php-mbstring.x86_64 which deals with some of the string validation and processing for the addresses.  However, being called via Ajax made tracking this down incredibly difficult

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking that there is some module overriding saveBilling method.
Thats why logs doesnt works. You may be in wrong method.

Are you using PHPstorm? Magicento?
PHPStorm shows if any method is overide. It looks like:
[image: file:///home/s-ksiamro/Obrazy/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%202017-11-28%2014-27-27.png]
at the left you can see:

[image: file:///home/s-ksiamro/Obrazy/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%202017-11-28%2014-26-16.png]

point with white arrow (left one) says that current method is override. Click there to move.
point with red arrow (right one) says that current function is overriding different. You can also click there to move.

EDIT1:

try to enable PHP logs to index.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then go to checkout page and see results.
Also use Browser console to check for errors.
Also check logs:
- var/log/system.log
- var/log/exceptions.log

It should help with debugging.
However better idea is to install and configure xdebug. Then debugging code step by step - very useful :)

Comment: Well I thought that too but a log works two lines higher in the controller, before the  $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId), but not after so I know that method is being called.  I do have commercebug (Alan Storm's thingy)

Comment: have made that clearer in my Q.

Comment: I installed phpstorm and no, the methods are not overwritten.

Comment: I just edit my post, let me know if that helps

Comment: thanks for your continued efforts. I do have them enabled already.  I am reaching the conclusion that it might be a database write issue as I have now discovered that customer/account/createpost/ also fails the same way at the point of $customer->save() .  will keep digging

Comment: xdebug connected with PHPstorm will be very usefull anyway. Anyway can You describe when exactly problem occur? After install any module, upgrade, whatever? I have an idea that problem is when Magento is trying to get "$this->getOnepage()". In  this case flow will never  go into saveBilling() method. Try to debug getOnepage() function

Comment: When submitting the initial address, the process successfully calls the getOnepage()->saveBilling()  and I can log out objects and data to the point where the saveBilling does the "return array();"   Nothing progresses at this point though. No further action happens in the onepagecontroller and an empty/failed response is returned.

Comment: Am not sure if anything is actually being saved db-wise at this point.

Comment: Must be a server/db config issue as it works on the development server but not live.

Comment: Argh, the customer details ARE being saved into the DB and can be seen in the admin.

Comment: Hmmm  it seems to have (Magically) cleared itself.  I think it may have been the APC cache in combination with a problematic session. Disabling APC seems to allow the site to work.

Comment: Have awarded the bounty as needed to and, whilst it wasn't actually the correct answer, it did offer some useful suggestions and PHPstorm is quite interesting.

Comment: The answer, in the end, turned out to be a missing server module that allowed for the string manipulation (I think) that was used in the checkout address checking.

Comment: ouh. Which one module?

Comment: I couldn't remember but have checked my yum history: php-mbstring.x86_64.   http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you added **formkey** in your custom templates after patched??

you need to add that in 
templates/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

```
    <form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getPostAction() ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
.....
```

And in billing.phtml, shipping.phtml & payment.phtml inside the form.

Without the formkey ajax request to saveBilling request will not work.

Comment: yes, formkeys all present in the form and the passed form data.  Good thought though.  It does all seem to be working now though.  Disabling the APC cache and clearing out all session data seems to have done something that works...